# HTML5 three page layout column

Tags: html, css, layout

Nearly took me 4 hours to even get to this point. I really just can't jot down the layout of a three column. This is the best I can get to so far, this is my css:

```
#header {text-align: center;}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: #FAFAFA;
     color: #003300;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

#center { margin:0 210px 0 160px;

}

#right{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}

#footer { text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

#left a {text-decoration: none;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
         color: #FFFFCC;
         font-weight:bold;
         border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
         padding: 5px;}

figure{}

#left a:link { background-color: #003366; }
#left a:visited { background-color: #48751A; }
#left a:hover {border: 3px inset #333333; }

#left ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }
```

this is the website for my project:

http://younani.com/finalsite/finalindex.html

As you could see the left, center ,and right column are not aligned. Also, is there way to fit the site according to the page being maximized or normal? I am new to building websites. Also as you could see in the about us page the navigation touches the center column, is their anyway around that? If there's any more information needed to be provided, let me know please. Thanks.

Comment: You would probably do good using (and hopefully looking at/learning from) a css framework ( http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/ wouldn't be a bad start). Even if you don't use them there's a lot to be picked up from open-source tested frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `float:left;` to your `#center` div and they will align properly. And yes you can use percentages instead of pixels to make it so that the containers are a percentage of the screen size.

**EDIT TO SHOW 3 COLUMN LAYOUT**

This is a general 3 column layout, you will need to tweak some things when you start adding your own styles, but it works and it shows how I'm clumping `#left, #center, #right` together and using the power of the `cascade` of CSS to over-ride the previous settings.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

   <title>Younani Flower's</title>

   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <style>
        #container {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #container div {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #header {}

        #left,
        #center,
        #right {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }

        #center {
            width: 494px;
        } 

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

   </style>

</head>



<body>
    <div id="container" class="clearfix">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Younani Flowers</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- Left Column -->
        <div id="left">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="finalindex.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="financing.html">Ocassions</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Center Column -->
        <div id="center">
            <p>Main content</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Right Column -->
        <div id="right">
            <p>Secondary Sidebar</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer" class="clear">     
            <p>&copy; Copyright "Younani" Michael Younani 2012<br /><a href="mailto:YounaniFlower@gmail.com">YounaniFlowers@gmail.com</a></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That did align it, but if you check the about us page, when I insert the paragraph, you see how it unaligned everything?

Comment: I know a lot of sites will show adding margins to create a center column. But I prefer widths. Using widths your issue is solved immediately, add a width of `width: 600px` to your center div and turn off the margins and it will work fine. Then add in a `margin-left` of how many you want to make it align where you want. Or just use auto to center it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I added the width of 600px and margin-left: auto to the center div. Its aligned now, but the center touches the navs on the left, is that because I choose to write auto? I can post the css again if I confused you.

Comment: Yeah that probably did it. I would add a margin left to it. I usually try to stay consistent with my margins. For example, if you line up a three column I would float all three left, set their widths, and then add a margin left to them. All are now very consistent and you could even group them and just override the necessary changes using the cascade. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did first but since they would touch one another, I did research and found that floating right column to the right would work, but in my case it didn't. As of now, I floated all three columns to the left. I margin-left: auto; all three. The center still touches the nav on side. I'm a bit confused on what you mean by overriding the necessary changes using the cascade. =x  And i tried to downsize and upsize the width but that didn't help.

Comment: Ok. hold up - I'll update my answer in a second with more in-depth code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20433/discussion-between-michael-younani-and-coldcoder)